# Is sum of forces always zero along the axis that momentum is conserved?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum

Lately I've been approaching problems with conservation of momentum of systems, I was wondering, if I draw the free body diagram, then write the equations and then add them togheter; if momentum is conserved along an axis I will always get that the sum of the forces must be equal to zero in the equations of the dynamic along the axis where momentum is conserved, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Net force is the rate of change of momentum with respect to time: for a system of constant masses $m_i$ with velocities $v_i$ and accelerations $a_i$:

$\vec F = \Sigma \vec F_i = \frac{d}{dt}(\Sigma m_i\vec v_i) = \Sigma m_i\vec a_i$

If total tracked momentum $\Sigma m_i\vec v_i$ does not change, the net force is zero.

Note that if we are tracking all the momenta of **all** the masses in a given interaction (including the planet, if the interaction includes friction with the ground, air resistance, gravity, etc), the net force and the change of total system momentum will always be zero, since there aren't any un-tracked objects left to be applying a force from outside. Every force prompts an equal and opposite force as indicated by the Third Law. This principle is conservation of momentum.

Comment: thank you, so basically I can check if momentum is conserved if the sum of the forces is zero, and if momentum is conserved the sum of the forces must be zero